# CSS - Best way to add full width column background colour to columns inside container

Tags: css

I've got a design I need to complete with 2 columns, the content inside the columns needs to line up with the container that's used across the site.

The issue I've got is on the design the second column has a background colour that stretches to the edge of the viewport.

If you look at the JSfiddle/code below I have a working solution if you uncomment the .col::after code at the bottom, however I was hoping there might be a cleaner more simple way of achieving this?

Cheers

https://jsfiddle.net/qksmpfrv/

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 80px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  padding: 80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.col:last-child {
  background: grey;
}


/* .col:last-child::after {
        background: grey;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        width: 500px;
    } */
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :after is the best way, that I know, to achieve the result

Comment: keep after, remove width:500px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about moving the grid outside the max-width container and then adding a max-width inside the columns:

Advantages of this approach over an `after`

1. will always be the width of the screen no matter how wide the monitor is - the after approach will only cover screens up to 2400px wide (I know not many screens are this big, but sometimes you might want to display your site at a marketing event and those screens may be)
2. you are not creating an extra 500px box off screen for smaller resolutions (so less rendering time for things like mobile and tablet)
3. You don't have to use a hack on every column you want to stretch to the edge
4. It's just nicer and easier to maintain

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 80px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.inner {
  max-width: 700px;
  padding: 80px;     /* move padding to inner */
}

.col:first-child .inner {
  margin-left: auto;   /* push this to the right if no wide enough to fill col */
}

.col:last-child {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<!-- move grid outside container -->
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="inner">
      <!-- add inner containers with max-width of 700px (half of your container) -->
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="inner">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it. Thanks for the solution.